# Administrator verification for user role type

Tags: users

Is it possible to add admin verification for specific user roles.  For instance, my site has three user roles, one of which would should get verified before gaining access to the content.  I realise there is an option " Visitors, but administrator approval is required" in the 
people > administration tab, but this would be for all users.

I'm managing roles directly through Drupal 7 and not using any modules such as profile2.

Thank in advance,

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the option you refer to ("Visitors, but administrator approval is required") is not for all users.  It only applies to the *Anonymous* user role, and means that the Anonymous user is allowed to register at the site (gaining the *Authenticated* user role), but only after the administrator has approved the registration.

The "standard" way of doing this in Drupal is to set up the site so that the "Anonymous" user role does not get access to the content you want to reserve for verified users.

Then, to gain access the anonymous user must 1) register; and 2) the administrator must approve the registration (using the option you refer to).

How would this model work for your site?

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/apply_for_role
The Apply for Role module allows users to apply for roles and allows role administrators to approve the role applications.

Maybe this module can help you
https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be the Registration Role With Approval, which sounds like it does exactly what you need it to. I've used it before with success.

> This module lets administrator to select roles that will be available
>   for selection on registration form. It also allows to select which
>   roles needs admin approval.
>
> During registration user will be presented with optional checkboxes
>   where he can select a one or more of available roles. If role needs
>   admin approval, user account will be blocked until approved by admin.
>   Email will be sent to administrator (configurable) with roles that are
>   requested and username of user who request it.

https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_role_with_approval